# Why does Kurotsuchi Mayuri wear makeup?

Tags: bleach

Is there some reason Kurotsuchi Mayuri in Bleach dresses the way he does, and wears a mask/makeup? Or is it just because he is somewhat crazy?

Comment: i think it's by choice. during the Rukia Rescue after loosing to Uryu and stabbing himself at the end we seem him reformed without his "makeup" and with blue hair and while i haven't seen up to it it appears later in the series he changes how his "makeup" looks and his blue hair is visible

Comment: Might just be to hide his scars.

Comment: Do you want to know how he got those scars?

Comment: No, but if you point me to the related episode/movie or manga, that'd be great. :)

Comment: @axel22 I think he just want to hide his scars, and he is somewhat crazy at his work. The scene in which Kurotsuchi Mayuri shows his scars is in chapter 172, around page 12-16. You can see them on this link http://mangafever.me/read2/bleach/172/14 .

Answer (score 1):

Based on his demeanor, I think it's for psychological warfare purposes in order to frighten or intimidate his opponent. He's going for the whole "Otherworldly Mad-Scientist" vibe.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your answers.